# If I use histedit frequently, will MercurialMq be a better fit?

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-queue, mercurial-extension

When I'm working on some particular feature I often fix other pretty much unrelated but easy-to-fix stuff. I make some "dirty" commits during the work. When the feature is finished, I spend a lot of time with hg histedit trying to rearrange all the changes I've made to get nice clean commits before I push them into public. The process is kind of tedious and error-prone, I believe there should be some other way to work.

I've recently found out [MercurialMq](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/MqExtension) extension. Am I right thinking that it was designed exactly to facilitate the process I described?

**UPD**: What about [Shelve](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ShelveExtension)? How these two are related?

Answer (score 1):

These days, there is a better solution, namely the 
[Evolve extension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/EvolveExtension).

Answer (score 0):

Yes. MQ ideally fits into "some set of WIP tasks" and designed for this job

Answer (score 0):

MQ was indeed designed for the kind of thing you're doing. Shelve is much simpler; you can put aside uncommitted changes (some or all) so they don't get in the way of mercurial operations. I use it a lot, because I *don't* want to bother with a lot of rearranging.